# Jira + Liferay Integration through OAuth

Tags: oauth, liferay, jira, opensocial

I created public/private key using keytool and exported the certificate into rsaSigningKey.pem. Placed this file in liferay-data-folder/opensocial/.

Configured Incoming authentication in Application Links of Jira with

**Consumer key** - www.myliferay.com

**Consumer Name** - Liferay

**Public key** - public key text from rsaSigningKey.pem file.

Public key greyed out and saved the configuration.

Added the OpenSocial gadget onto the Liferay page. Gave the url of activityStream of Jira and in Manage OAuth section selected RSA_private and gave the consumer key as www.myliferay.com. Saved the configuration.

My activity stream in Liferay shows empty.  When I checked the liferay console, it shows an error of **jodd.bean.BeanException: Simple property not found:  oAuthConsumerId Invalid property: 'OAuthConsumerImpl#oAuthconsumerId (actual: 'OAuthConsumerImpl#oAuthConsumerId', forced=false)**

Where am I going wrong?  should the consumer key be the CN of public/private key creation?

Regards,
Anantha